# QWebView not rendering all the website information

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qtwebview

I have a piece of code that renders an HTML file into a QWebView object.

This is the code:

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView as QWebView

    # create web browser for the map
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
    web_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(frame)
    webView = QWebView()
    web_layout.addWidget(webView)
    url = 'map.html'
    this_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
    webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(this_path, url)))

    frame.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is that the QWebView object is not rendering the web page as it is:

QWebView rendering:
[image]

This is the correct rendering:
[image]

I'd like to know how to fix this.

[This is the html file](https://gist.github.com/SanPen/a4102da1794f3f297f160b40b1de2ad5)

Comment: share your .html, PyQt4 or PyQt5?

Comment: html shared, it is pyqt5

Comment: I have tried with QtWebKitWidgets and it works correctly, you could try with QtWebEngineWidgets, check the following gist for more details.
 https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/35a5a88def67d5aad48ea63ef0749b1e

Comment: The problem was my PyQt version, I had 5.9 and by installing the latest (5.12) everything worked out